# Installing node-sass errors with 'ELIFECYCLE'

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I install npm and work, but I can not install node-sass. The next message following;

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "scss"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! one@1.0.0 scss: `node-sass -watch scss -o css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the one@1.0.0 scss script 'node-sass -watch scss -o css'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the one package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-sass -watch scss -o css
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs one
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls one
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/maty/Desktop/MyFirstProyect/npm-debug.log
```

I install sass use;

npm install node-sass
sudo npm install -g sass

I checked the version, I made an easy sass code example.

Someone, could you help me?

Comment: I believe you're installing sass incorrectly, have you installed Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version and node-sass version.
Mine was  **"node-sass":"4.5.3"** node version i changed that too **"node-sass":"^4.6.0"**
(change this based on your node version by referring the below attached image) in package.json dev dependency and ran npm install. Installation was success and working fine.try this
[image]